# Git reverting old version as new commit across file name changes

Tags: git

I want to revert to an old version and commit it as a new version:

So I do:

```
git checkout 1778b26 .
```

However, if there was a renamed file involved between the latest version and the version I am checking out, both file names would exist. `git clean -fdx` does not fix this.

How do I make sure that , when I check out that old version as new, the files and directories are exactly as the old version?

Comment: What's wrong with `git revert commit`?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- mark your current state: git branch tmp
- reset index and working tree to your old commit: `git reset --hard oldSHA1`
  However, this also moves HEAD back and lose the history of the commits after `oldSHA1`.
- reset HEAD to `yourCurrentBranch` previous `HEAD` (marked `tmp`):
  `git reset --soft tmp`

From there, you can add and commit: that will create a new commit which will have the exact same content as the old SHA1.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
git diff 1778b26..HEAD | git apply -R --index
```

This generates a diff between that other commit and your current `HEAD`, then reverses the diff, applies it to `HEAD`, and then records the changes in the index.

This should work as long as you do not have any binary files in your repository.